LangChain Hugging face model for PromptTemplate class
when invoking the Intel/dynamic_tinybert model in the HuggingFaceEndpoint/HuggingFaceHub class in langchain for a translation/Q&A task, one persistent error was as below:
Bad request:
Error in inputs: value is not a valid dict
even when passing the input in the prompt as a dict value type, the error was the same.
The HuggingFaceEndpoint/HuggingFaceHub class was used for the langchain example but the repo_id, which was previously google/flan-t5-x1 was replace with Intel/dynamic_tinybert as the former is no longer available.
what is the ideal input format for the model, when using langchain?
ref: https://www.pinecone.io/learn/series/langchain/langchain-intro/
Thanks
I have tried other model but the same invalid input error was returned i.e.
Bad request:
Error in inputs: value is not a valid dict

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

eventually, I found that the

mistralai/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.2

model could take a string as input prompt that returns a valid response.
